# Include resume for download on click

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I added resume pdf file to react asset folder so it could be download on click.
it works fine on a local server when I run npm start but its doesn't work when its built through AWS amplify. can you please tell me what Im doing wrong?
the file downloads but says could not be opened file damaged or doesn't recognize.Also, file size is different. downloaded file is lot smaller than original

```
import HRK from './Assets/HRK.png';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import { Github, Linkedin, FilePerson } from 'react-bootstrap-icons';
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Resume from './Assets/Resume.pdf'

const NaviLink = () => {

  const tooltipGithub = (props) => (
      <Tooltip id="link-tooltip" style={{color:'white'}} {...props}>Github</Tooltip>
  )
  const tooltipLinkedin = (props) => (
      <Tooltip id="link-tooltip" style={{color:'white'}} {...props}>LinkedIn</Tooltip>
  )
  const tooltipResume = (props) => (
      <Tooltip id="link-tooltip" style={{color:'white'}} {...props}>Resume</Tooltip>
  )

  return (
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" sticky="top">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <img
              alt="HRK"
              src={HRK}
              width="70"
              height="70"
              className="d-inline-block align-top"
              style={{borderRadius: '50px'}}
            />
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Container>
          <Nav>
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#skills">Skills</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#project">Project</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
            <OverlayTrigger placement='bottom' overlay={tooltipGithub}>
              <a href="https://github.com/HyungKim0105" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                <Github style={{color:'white',height:'30',width:'30',marginLeft:'0.5rem',marginRight:'0.5rem'}}/>
              </a>
            </OverlayTrigger>
            <OverlayTrigger placement='bottom' overlay={tooltipLinkedin}>
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/hyungkim0105" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                <Linkedin style={{color:'white',height:'30',width:'30',marginRight:'0.5rem'}}/>
              </a>
            </OverlayTrigger>
            <OverlayTrigger placement='bottom' overlay={tooltipResume}>
              <a href={Resume} download="HyungKim_Resume.pdf">
                <FilePerson style={{color:'white',height:'30',width:'30',marginRight:'2rem'}}/>
              </a>
            </OverlayTrigger>
          </Nav>
      </Navbar>
  )
}

export default NaviLink
```

I tried using Link in react router Dom but that just show empty page on local build.
(maybe its because Im using a icon in-between Link.)

tried to put file in public folder with href="resume.pdf" and href="/resume.pdf". Both didn't work with or without the download.

also tried to link it my iCloud but couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `download` availability is [defined like this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp):

```
 <a href="/resume.pdf" download>
```

Be sure your resume is in the same directory, or give it its respective pathname.

Alternatively, you can use AWS S3 in AWS Amplify, by writing `amplify add storage` in the `CLI` to the project, and then obtain the file with `Storage.get()`. Read more about this [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js/).

Comment: thank you for your answer but tried it and that doesn't work.  the download doesn't work even in the local environment and it also downloads as html. if I add download="file.pdf", it downloads as pdf but the file is still broken. I guess I could try the s3 but Id would really like to know why this doesn't work in hosted environment but works in local environment.

Comment: Can you view the file by itself, without downloading it? Like it works just by double clicking in your OS on that file.

Comment: Yes it works when I click on the file on my computer. Also works on local machine through local server using npm start.  I went around the problem by building it locally on my machine and just uploading the build directly instead of having aws build it through GitHub and now everything works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with how AWS builds with GitHub. I ran npm run build on a local machine and uploaded the build folder to AWS and everything works fine. before I had opted for GitHub connected build. still not sure why it didn't work since build settings looked exactly the same.....

Comment: This is not a good long-term strategy, though.

Comment: Yeah… I guess I’ll look into amplifys build process to see if I missed something or go with you suggestion using s3 for the long term. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.